# Spaces and new lines with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Should I use `<br />` and `&nbsp;` in HTML to position elements, or should I just use CSS display:inline with padding/margin for positioning and all styling? what are pros and cons with both?

Comment: I smell a religious argument...

Comment: what is so funny with this question?

Comment: Nothing really, but there are no 'pros' of positioning elements with `&nbsp;` and `<br />` unless you are drawing ASCII art. This is a major reason for the existence of CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<br>` to represent a linebreak inside a block element and use `&nbsp;` to represent a non-breaking space inside an inline element. Nothing more. For the remnant just use CSS the smart way with help of under each the `display`, `float`, `padding` and/or `margin` properties.

Comment: when i use display:inline on a span element another element is still positioned to the right of the span element. shouldnt that one be in the next line?

Comment: @noname: no a `span` is an inline element and thus display inline does nothing to it. if you want the element on a new line use `display: block`.

Comment: A `span` is by default already inline. Either use a linebreak, or a block element, or close the parent block element and start a new block element.

Answer (score 4):

`<br />` has its uses, but if you find yourself using `&nbsp` a lot, I would consider finding better ways to align things.  `&nbsp;` is just ugly and clunky.

If it's tabular data, use a table.  Your life will be much happier.

If it's not tabular data, use css, as BalusC suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should position everything with css, and only use `<br />` (line break) and `&nbsp;` inside `<p>s`.
But this isn't an ideal world ;)

Answer (score 1):

`<br />` Can really go either way. But if you find yourself using it to adjsut paragraph spacing orsomething like this then you really have to ask yourself "is there a reason why im using breaks instead of applying a class to adjust margins?" `&nbsp;` on the other rarely if ever makes any kind of sense outside of a paragraph (`<p />`) and half the time theres not much use for it ther any how as using `text-indent` is preferable for indenting the first paragraph and much to the chigirn of Editors everywhere im completely opposed to the double space prepending of senetences on the web - as far as im concerned that is a print only thing.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you also have the new 
http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#w

the answer is not black and white, it depends on your content, sometimes it should be 
 and in some cases the   so the content will be on a single line.

if you want it as block you can use

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS margin and padding will give you greater flexibility to make adjustments later on.